# Animated Gif Optimization

Tags: image, optimization, compression, animated-gif

I wonder, what is the best solution to **compress** an **animated gif** without loosing too much quality?
Is there a software or a website (like [tinypng.org](http://tinypng.org) does with png) that can **really** help?
Or am I stock with what I got after the Photoshop export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) ([GUI](http://imageoptim.com)) is such program although it optimizes mostly losslessly.

GIF file size is most dependent of pixel dimensions of the animation. Resampling to lower resolution may significantly reduce size.